# Can anyone recommend a free and online Greek-to-English dictionary?

Tags: resource-request, dictionary, greek

The dictionary may optionally render the Greek word with the Roman alphabet but must include one or more definitions in English that explain the meaning. In particular, I am trying to find out why "εκκλησάκι" and "παρεκκλήσι" are translated the same into English and hoping to read a full explanation of how they are different.

Comment: This question came from [here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20882) per [WavesWashSands'](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/10021/waveswashsands) comment.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure if any of the resources I've listed will be able to answer your question, [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/) fairly well. Make sure you select Greek-English in the drop-down box below the search bar. [Dict](https://www.dict.com/%CE%91%CE%B3%CE%B3%CE%BB%CE%BF-%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%B7%CE%BD%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%BF/?) also offers a Greek-English dictionary, and [Glosbe](https://glosbe.com/el/en/) works as well.